# Are Turkish Bay Leaves "Normal" Bay leaves?

Tags: herbs, bay-leaf

I recently saw a recipe that called for Turkish Bay Leaves. Is this any different than the kind I would find in a standard spice bottle labeled "Bay Leaves", or is this a form of exotic marketing? Are there even different types of Bay Leaves?

Comment: "Normal" Bay leaves... As opposed to "abnormal" bay leaves? j/k... ;-)

Comment: There are at least three kinds of leaves sometimes considered bay leaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured I'd check the [site](http://www.mccormick.com/Products/Herbs-and-Spices/Spices-A-to-Z/Bay-Leaves.aspx) of the brand I use. Turns out they are Turkish:

> The bay tree is native to the Mediterranean region and Asia Minor. The bay or laurel tree grows well in the subtropics and is cultivated today as a spice in the Far East as well as the Canary Islands, France, Belgium, Mexico, Central America and Turkey (where McCormick's bay leaves are grown).

Answer (score 5):

**Are there even different types of Bay Leaves?**

There is the California Bay Laurel  *Umbellularia californica*.

Turkish Bay is *Laurus nobilis*

(https://nicholsgardennursery.wordpress.com/2008/06/20/laurus-nobilis-the-true-bay/)

We have an California Bay Laurel (AKA Oregon Myrtle) growing in our yard. While looking the same and smelling like normal store bought bay leafs like from Spice Island, it is 10 times more pungent. I used it once and that was the last time.

Answer (score 4):

According to [The Spice House](http://www.thespicehouse.com/spices/turkish-bay-leaves-whole-and-ground):

> The flavor of these Turkish bay leaves
>   is far milder and more complex than
>   that of domestic bay; it adds a subtly
>   sweet astringency to dishes. Only one
>   or two are needed to enhance a whole
>   roast, pot of soup or stew.

Answer (score 4):

I consider them "normal"; they're the oval-shaped bay leaves. There's a "California" bay leaf variety that has elongated leaves and a slightly different flavor.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

So there are two plants which are called "bay leaves"; the Turkish Bay Laurel (Laurus Nobilis) and the California Bay Laurel (Umbellularia californica), as other answers have noted.  What's "normal" honestly depends on where you live and what kind of recipe you're making.

European recipes are going to expect bay leaves to be Turkish, because that's the tree that originated bay leaves as a spice in Europe.  Mexican recipes, and ones from the American West, are going to expect California Bay.  For any other region, it's kind of random.

If you buy dried "bay leaves", what you get is going to depend on sourcing; you're best reading the label.  The two species are largely interchangeable in most recipes, which makes life easier, with one exception: if you specifically need fresh bay leaves, go Turkish.  California bay leaves are less flavorful when fresh, and have a waxy texture.

Comment: There is a third one: Cinnamomum tamala, aka Tejpat. This is what an indian - and there are a lot of them on this planet - is likely to understand if you say "bay leaf".

Comment: Huh!  That's a new one on me, and I lived in Nepal.  I guess they aren't as frequently used there?

Comment: Might be more regional that I thought...

Comment: Articles say Nepal is one of the places they're eaten.  I think it's just that the leaves aren't used that frequently, or they're used in ground-up form.

Comment: Technically, whole bay leaves usually aren't eaten :)